# Angular - Unit test with ng5-slider

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a component that I've used ng5-slider on it.

```
    form: FormGroup;
    cities = [];
    hddTypes = [];
    minValue = 0;
    maxValue = 72000;
    options: Options = {
        floor: 0,
        ceil: 72000,
        translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
            switch (label) {
                case LabelType.Low:
                    return `<b>Min:</b> ${value} GB`;
                case LabelType.High:
                    return `<b>Max:</b> ${value} GB`;
                default:
                    return `${value} GB`;
            }
        },
        step: 1000,
        showTicks: true
    };
    .
    .
    .
```

I created a unit test for this component but I've got this error:

**Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ng5-slider'.**

What is the best practice to add `ng-5 slider` in my test?

Here is my test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {SearchComponent} from './search.component';

describe('StaticComponent', () => {
    let component: SearchComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
    const formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [
                    SearchComponent,
                ],
                imports: [
                    CommonModule,
                    ReactiveFormsModule
                ],
                providers: [
                    // reference the new instance of formBuilder from above
                    { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilder }
                ]
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        // pass in the form dynamically
        component.form = formBuilder.group({
            location: null,
            type: null,
            ram: null,
            storage: null,
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzbHu.png
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the Angular's [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests), One way is to provide stub components.

As the purpose of unit testing is to test the component as a unit by mocking any external dependencies. So, you should just be bothered about the child components interface, not the implementation details.

before describe block, create a stub component:

```
@Component({selector: 'ng5-slider', template: ''})
class NgSliderStubComponent {
    @Input() value;
}
```

Then, in configureTestingModule, add NgSliderStubComponent in the declartions array.

```
declarations: [SearchComponent, NgSliderStubComponent],
```